# Which ingress controller should I use to support WebSocket in a AWS k8s cluster deployed by kops?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kops, nginx-ingress, traefik-ingress

I have a cluster on AWS installed via kops. Now I need to expose a WebSocket service (with security enabled, the wss://) to the outside world. There are different ingress controllers, nginx, traefik, ELBs, ALBs. Which one is the suggested and:

- easy to deploy and config
- support http://, https://, ws://, and wss://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In my opinion this question is opinion based and too broad. Please try to avoid such questions as there is not one solution that is the best.*

I was able to find plenty resources about nginx and websockets. I do not have production experience with configuring this, but I think you might find this helpful.

> NGINX is a popular choice for an Ingress Controller for a variety of
>   features:
>
> - Websocket, which allows you to load balance Websocket applications.
> - SSL Services, which allows you to load balance HTTPS applications.
> - Rewrites, which allows you to rewrite the URI of a request before    sending it to the application.
> - Session Persistence (NGINX Plus only), which guarantees that all the    requests from the same client are always passed to the same
>     backend    container.
> - Support for JWTs (NGINX Plus only), which allows NGINX Plus to    authenticate requests by validating JSON Web Tokens (JWTs).

The most important part with nginx is the [annotation](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/websocket#websocket-support) - which specifies which services are Websocket services. Some more information about usage and [configuration.](https://medium.com/ww-engineering/k8s-ws-aws-elb-nlb-5a23834d4f14) Also useful [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) about configuration of nginx ingress, although it is about GKE it might be useful.